# Many to many insertion error Call to a member function Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a trouble in many to many insertion. My code in controller is right. After I add the two data which is successful, the third time I try to insert produce an error:

> Call to a member function bagcollects() on null

and the error is on this code

```
$collection->bagcollects()->attach($bagcollect->id);
```

I just don't understand why this error occurred!

I'll show the whole code of CollectionsController store method:

```
public function addbag(Request $request){
    $collection = Collection::find($request->input('collection_id'));
    $bagcollect = Bagcollect::create([
        'bag_id' => $request->input('bag_id'),
        'weight' => $request->input('weight')
    ]);
    $collection->bagcollects()->attach($bagcollect->id);
    return redirect()->route('collections.show', ['collection'=> $collection->id]);
}
```

Migration on collections

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
if(!Schema::hasTable('collections')){
    Schema::create('collections', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('assignment_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('assignment_id')->references('id')->on('assignments')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamp('collected_on');
    });
}
```

Migration on bagcollects

```
Schema::create('bagcollects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('bag_id')->unsigned();
    $table->double('weight', 8, 2);
    $table->foreign('bag_id')->references('id')->on('bags');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Migration bagcollect_collection

```
Schema::create('bagcollect_collection', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('bagcollect_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('collection_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('bagcollect_id')->references('id')->on('bagcollects');
    $table->foreign('collection_id')->references('id')->on('collections');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

collections show.blade.php add modal

```
<!-- ADD MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="addModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">New Collection</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"> 
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('collections.addbag') }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}


                            <div class="row form-group">  

                                <input class="form-control" name = "collection_id" id="collection_id" value="{{$collection->id}}" type="hidden">
                                 <div class="{{ $errors->has('bag') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <label for="bag_id">Bag</label>
                                             <select class="form-control" required id="bag" name="bag_id">
                                                 <option value="" data-hidden="true"  
                                                    selected="selected">
                                                </option>
                                                    @foreach($bags as $bag)
                                                        <option value= "{{ $bag->id }}">
                                                              {{ $bag->name }} 
                                                        </option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                              </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                  <div class="{{ $errors->has('weight') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <label for="weight">Weight</label>
                                             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="weight" name= "weight" required>
                                        </div>
                                  </div>

                            </div>   

                            <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-fill pull-right" id="form-button-add">
                                Create
                            </button>

                            <button  data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="btn btn-basic pull-right" style="margin-right: 2%">
                                Cancel
                            </button>             
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                        </form>                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Collection.php model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'assignment_id',
    'bag_id'
];

public $timestamps = false;

public function assignment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Assignment');
}

public function bagcollects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Bagcollect');
}
```

Bagcollect.php

```
protected $fillable = [
    'bag_id',
    'weight'
];

public function collections()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Collection');
}

public function bag()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Bag');
}
```

BagcollectCollection.php

```
protected $table = "bagcollect_collection";

protected $fillable = [
    'bagcollect_id',
    'collection_id',

];
```

Comment: can you share relation model ?

Comment: `Collection` is already a class in Laravel; you might run into issues with your `Collection` model vs the `Collection` helper (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections). Consider changing your table/model names.

Comment: @TimLewis she probably use with its own namespace, shouldn't be a problem..

Comment: @HasanTıngır Yes, probably, but without seeing the `use` statement, it's hard to say. Changed my wording on the comment it make it more of a warning.

Comment: can you dump `$collection` var with dd() method ?

Comment: I do the dd($collection). On my 1st add, the collection id still exists, but on my 2nd add, it show null or no collection id I pass. I'll add the view of it

Comment: @MariaTheresaChavez Can you share your model?

Comment: Ok I'll post my model in a while

Comment: @ChristianGallarmin I already post the model. Check it out

Answer (score 3):

> Call to a member function ... on `null`

Means that you're trying to call a function on a `null` object. Review your code:

```
$collection = Collection::find($request->input('collection_id'));
```

With your current logic, `$collection` could be `null`, so calling

```
$collection->bagcollects() ...
```

Will throw this error.

Debug the result of `Collection::find(...)` and ensure that `$collection` is not `null`.

Comment: I try to use dd in my controller code. When I enter the data, the collection_id is passed from the show.blade.php, but on the second try, the collection_id became null. I don't know because I think it should be passed knowing the it is in the show and the collection_id is existing on that view